# Anrisamy XSS validation not working for JavaScript <div/onmouseover> injection

Tags: scala, antixsslibrary

I tried applying`<div/onmouseover='alert("hacked")'> style="x:">` string to attack, but it was not blocked by antisamy library. Does anyone know why it's not prevented against Antisamy library?

Comment: This might be better logged as a bug with the author. If it is open source, maybe they have a public bug tracker?

Comment: It's incorrect ly formatted HTML. Cut and paste error or what you really used?

Comment: Yes I am looking for its forum or support team as I am not aware of it.